# Fortify disappointing scan behaviour

Tags: security, fortify, static-code-analysis

When I scan my .net code with Fortify SCA I get disappointing results depending if I start the scanning from the subproject folder or the top main project folder (the main project of all the .net projects).

```
[.net main project folder]
   [.net subproject folder 1]
   [.net subproject folder 2]
```

Some source files are reported as issues with one scan approach and disappear completely in the other approach.

Have you also encountered this problem?
I'm using HPE Security Fortify SCA 17.20

Comment: Welcome to the world of static code analysis. Don't ask how much your company paid for the tool you use.

Comment: Thanks Marek Puchalski, I feel better now.